# Import a uMap into Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have created a map with uMap, e.g. http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/de/map/raspail_1#19/48.84307/2.32840

Now I want to use the Leaflet API to embed this stuff (no iframe). Is there a way to e.g. export this map as JSON and import it into Leaflet. Or are there any possibilities to do this?

Comment: the link you've provided is giving 404

Comment: i've updated the link, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the uMap supports it natively.  What I have suggested below is hacky, but if the information means enough to you its a way to get it.

I started the devtools in chrome `[F12]`.  I then navigated to the page you gave and clicked on the network tab of the tools.  If you click on one of the entries that have what appears to be a numeric folder name you should see something that resemble the screenshot I added below. Each one of these folders seems to correspond to some data files (alan-fout.kml in the highlighted item in the pic).  This is GeoJson that you could copy off, paste in a file and reference in a leaflet app.  What isn't here is the stylings of those data items, which you would have to replicate with leaflet.

Instead of this, you may just prefer to find a tool that converts kml that you would have uploaded to uMap to GeoJson if that's the format you prefer.  Leaflet also has a series of plugins that can consume formats like kml.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can Download the Data in GeoJson, KML and GPX. Go to the "more" button in the left > Share Button > Download raw data

[image: download data from umap]

Comment: maybe you have to activate the more Button in "map settings" > "user interface options" > "Do you want to display the «more» control?"